# How to make this Javascript function quicker (less CPU intensive)

Tags: javascript, optimization

Got quite easy function below, to move smoothly image to other location. Its from game, so move image of player +30 pixels left for example and move map +30 pixels left also.

Problem is all working as should except its slow. On my modern CPU i7 930 2.8 Ghz its ultra smooth and quick, but on netbook with 1.8 Ghz cpu its very slow. Also on better but still low-end hardware this function is laggy (image is moving not that smooth) and also need more time to finish same movement.

How to make this function less cpu intensive?

```
var blokada = 0;
var blokada2 = 0;

function translate(elem, x, y, toff, loff, delay2) {
    if (document.getElementById(elem) && blokada == 0) {
        blokada = 1;
        var elem = document.getElementById(elem);
        var left = loff,
            top = toff,
            dx = x,
            dy = y, //top - y,
            i = 1,
            count = delay2,
            delay = delay2 * 2;

        function loop() {
            if (i >= count) {
                blokada = 0;
                return;
            }
            i += 1;
            elem.style.left = (left - (dx * i / count)).toFixed(0) + 'px';
            elem.style.top = (top - (dy * i / count)).toFixed(0) + 'px';
            setTimeout(loop, delay);
        }
        loop();
    }
}

function translate2(elem, x, y, toff, loff, delay2) {

    if (document.getElementById(elem) && blokada2 == 0) {
        blokada2 = 1;
        var elem = document.getElementById(elem);

        var left = loff,
            top = toff,
            dx = left - x,
            dy = top - y,
            i = 1,
            count = delay2,
            delay = delay2;

        function loop() {
            if (i >= count) {
                blokada2 = 0;
                return;
            }
            i += 1;
            elem.style.left = (left - (dx * i / count)).toFixed(0) + 'px';
            elem.style.top = (top - (dy * i / count)).toFixed(0) + 'px';

            setTimeout(loop, delay);
        }
        loop();
    }
}

translate2('player', x, y, 120, 120, 10); //5
translate('map3', x, y, 0, 0, 10);
```

Comment: Try using `Math.round()` or `| 0` (if you don't care about proper sub pixel rounding) instead of `toFixed(0)`. Also, if performance is an issue, you should use [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) so the animations always take the same pre-defined length of time (if the user's computer is slow, it will just animate in less frames). You would also get a better response if you can reproduce a minimal working version on http://jsfiddle.net or similar.

Comment: I think this question is better asked at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please read about JavaScript optimization articles before asking this question. There are so many simple things you can optimize...

Answer (score 3):

You could use [css3 2d transform and translate()](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp) if you target modern browsers. There is a very good explanation from Paul Irish on why it is better to use translate than absolute position: http://paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/.

Your code would look like this:

```
var transform = "translate(" + left + "px," + top + "px)";
element.style.transform = transform;
element.style['-webkit-transform'] = transform;
element.style['-ms-transform'] = transform;
```

Answer (score 0):

Now this should be at least %60 faster than the original one. For it prefetches elem.style, and does integer division very very fast. And it will work with lame browsers too :)

```
var blokada = 0;
var blokada2 = 0;

function translate(elem, x, y, toff, loff, delay2) {
var elem = document.getElementById(elem);  // fetch once
  if (elem && blokada == 0) {
    blokada = 1;
    var sty = elem.style; // fetch once use many...
    // unnecessary assignments use loff and toff directly
    // var left = loff,
    //  top = toff,
    var  dx = x,
         dy = y, //top - y,
         i = 1,
         // unnecessary assignment
         // count = delay2,
         delay = delay2 * 2;

    function loop() {
      if (i >= delay2) {
        blokada = 0;
        return;
      }
      i += 1;
      sty.left = (loff - (~~(dx * i / delay2))) + 'px';
      sty.top = (toff - (~~(dy * i / delay2))) + 'px';
      setTimeout(loop, delay);
    }
    loop();
  }
}

function translate2(elem, x, y, toff, loff, delay2) {
var elem = document.getElementById(elem);  // fetch once
  if (document.getElementById(elem) && blokada2 == 0) {
    blokada2 = 1;
    // unnecessary assignments use loff and toff directly
    // var left = loff,
    //  top = toff,
    var sty = elem.style; // fetch once use many. 
      dx = loff - x,
      dy = toff - y,
      i = 1;
      // unnecessary assignments 
      //count = delay2,
      //delay = delay2;

    function loop() {
      if (i >= delay2) {
        blokada2 = 0;
        return;
      }
      i += 1;
      sty.left = (loff -(~~(dx * i / delay2))) + 'px';
      sty.top = (toff -(~~(dy * i / delay2))) + 'px';

      setTimeout(loop, delay2);
    }
    loop();
  }
}

translate2('player', x, y, 120, 120, 10); //5
translate('map3', x, y, 0, 0, 10);
```

Comment: That shouldn't affect it much as it's only done once in the *setup* of the animation. Worth doing it, but probably not the real reason it's slow.

Comment: Good idea, but removing one call to getElementById will have a very limited effect on overall performance, it's pretty fast.

Comment: @RobG, look the rest now please.

Answer (score 0):

Check out requestAnimationFrame (http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) it really sped up javascript animations I was doing a while ago. it basically means that you can stop using setTimeout and let the browser decide when it's best to calculate and paint the next frame.